# Sum Function with array argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

i'm starting studying javascript. I'm stuck with this exercise: Create a function that takes an array as argument and return the sum of all elements of the array.
I have written this code:

```js
function sum(table) {
  let x = table[0];
  let y = [table.length - 1];
  let totale = 0;
  for (count = x; count <= y; count++) {
    total += x;
    x += 1;
  };
  return total;
};


console.log(sum[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
```

I don't know why the result is undefined instead of 55. Thanks for helping.

Comment: `let y = [table.length - 1];` I don't think you want `y` to be an array.

Comment: Your variable is called `totale`, not `total`. And you want to iterate from `0`, not from `table[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

- `total` not `totale`
- the function call needs parentheses as `sum([…])`
- `y = table.length - 1` you want the length, not an array that holds the length
- `x = 0` you don't need to set it to the first element of the array
- `total += table[count];` you don't need to set it to x or to deal with x at all

```js
function sum(table) {
  let x = 0;
  let y = table.length - 1;
  let total = 0;
  for (count = x; count <= y; count++) {
    total += table[count];
  };
  return total;
};


console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
```

#### Quicker Solution

```js
function sum(table) {
  return table.reduce((p,c)=>p+c,0);
};


console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
```

Comment: Yeah, definitely not what I would do for a sum, but hopefully this will get him started.  He's new and just needs a guiding hand

Comment: `reduce` ftw imo

Comment: I don't think a total newbie should be using reduce- they should do it the longer way to understand how it works @stwilz

Comment: @chevybow of course.  though, one shouldn't avoid *reduce* simply because they are new.  The point is to learn *for* and *reduce* in this case.  But yes, if he's super new, maybe look into *reduce* in a week or two

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple of things.

You need to execute the sum function by calling like `sum([array elements])` .Note the `(` & `)` braces
Secondly `count <= y` will give undefined as it will exceed the length of the array. The array index starts from 0;

There is a typo here `totale`.

You can avoid these set of lines

```
let x = table[0];
let y = [table.length - 1];
```

if you just initialize the loop conditional statement like this

```
for (let count = 0; count < table.length; count++)
```

```js
function sum(table) {
  let x = 0
  for (let count = 0; count < table.length; count++) {
    x += table[count];
  };
  return x;
};
console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
```

Another option is to use the reduce method

```js
function sum(table) {
  return table.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    return acc += curr;
  }, 0) // 0 is the initial value
};
console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping. Totale was a mistake because i translated the cose before posted it. The real mistake was in console.log and in the iteration. Thanks again